# Change the color of the zoom window in Plotly?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

Plotly's default zoom window is a sort of "mask" effect where the zoom window is a light area and the outer part is dark:

[image]

Is there a way to change the style of this window, for example color it yellow and remove the "dark" outer part?